# Is there a list of safe prime numbers?

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, prime-numbers

I am looking for a list of precomputed [safe prime numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safe_prime). Where can I get such a list?

Comment: For ignorant people like me: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safe_prime

Comment: Maybe you can get them from the same company that will supply you with suggested passwords for your bank account.

Comment: @AndréNicolas All the smart people use correct horse battery staple.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I don't intend on using them as private keys, but as part of Pohlig-Hellman exponentation cipher. The use of that algorithm will be the most interesting of the ones I have heard about yet.

Answer (score 8):

Here's a list of the first 10000 numbers

http://oeis.org/A005385/b005385.txt

Comment: ^_^ ${}{}{}{}\;$

Answer (score 4):

With a little haskell, you can generate what you want.

```
ld n = ldf 2 n

ldf k n | rem n k == 0 = k
        | k^2 > n      = n
        | otherwise    = ldf (k+1) n

isprime n = isprime' (abs n)

isprime' n
  | n < 2 = False
  | otherwise = ld n == n

issophie n | not (isprime n)     = False
           | isprime (2 * n + 1) = True
           | otherwise           = False

sophies = filter issophie [2..]

safeprimes = map (\x -> 2 * x + 1) sophies
```

Then something like

```
first100safes = take 100 safeprimes

the5thsafe = safeprimes!!5
```

Many `safeprimes` will take a bit (`take 10000 safeprimes`).  You might want to capture them and keep them somewhere.  With a little modification, you can start with a big `sophie` and work up.  Maybe generate the next 10000 and add them to your list. Start things up and go get lunch.

Answer (score 3):

http://oeis.org/A005385
${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$